# html code instead of object from dom with the listener click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this function to capture the clicked element from a web page.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){
var domElement = $(event.target)[0]
console.log(domElement)
}, true)
```

this is the log of this function when I click on an input :

[image: first function log]

But I want the log to be as an object

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){
var domElement = $(event.target)
console.log(domElement)
}, true)
```

This is the log of the second function :

[image]

Here is an attempt using jQuery:

```js
$(document).on("click", "input", function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Is there a way to access to the input logged in the second picture ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use `.on`? Then try logging `this` inside the function. It should be what you're looking for

Comment: I tried doing it that way, the thing is that I get an error with the useCapture boolean when I try using on and logging the this.
Without the useCapture boolean, There are few domElements that won't be captured.

Comment: May you share an [mcve] of that code too?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','input',function(){console.log($(this).val());});`

Comment: What's wrong with your jquery example?

Comment: You are confusing what you see in console as html. The console displays an element object that way for developer convenience but the `target` is indeed an HtmlElement object

Comment: If you want to see the full Element structure, use `console.dir()`, not `console.log()`